# Engine reving harmful or beneficial

Tags: ford

Older, loud running truck; I was curious why people rev up the engine when working/troubleshooting vehicles. Is it damaging to the engine to rev it up really high for more than 30 min.?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! For more than 30 minutes or 30 seconds? And what quantifies as "high"? For the most part, revving an engine to rev the engine isn't good for it. Short blips or underload is not too big of a deal, but revving without a load for long periods of time can cause issues. Can even destroy an engine. It also depends on the engine involved and its maintenance history. Lots of factors.

Comment: The neighbor revs engine, nearly every day, what sounds like as high as it can, sometimes it seems like he is going to blow up the engine. Definitely more than 30 seconds. I remember my dad used to rev up engine when he was troubleshooting but not nearly as much or as long as neighbor does.

Comment: Some diesel engines have a rev limiter so that it can't be revved high when under no load, because the standard UK emissions test was damaging some engines.